# Transaction locked where it's not supposed to !`

Tags: mysql, sql, transactions

i have this code where i do three inserts in one transaction::

Transaction props::
was "REPEATABLE READ" by default but i've tried all the others levels (Globally, on session scope, and on local scope)

but still the code always get stuck at the third insert..
the code as follow::

```
insert into client(1);

insert into service (id,clientID) values (1,1);

insert into relTble (ParentServiceID,ChildServiceID) values (4,1);
```

having the fact that each of those inserts happens inside a class with "supposedly" new connection   but with Pconnect(..); which eventually gonna be in the same session..
mysql_error tells me ::
"lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction". 
but when i tried the same queries on server, in a transaction they've worked perfectly.
so please if you know anything about pconnect , such that it opens a new session after some time,or or.. please tell me!

Answer (score 0):

pconnect supports connection pooling for mysql. So if you have more than one connection to the database there is no guarantee that the individual requests will reuse the same connection. This must be enforced, otherwise you will have three different transactions.

Comment: and how to enforce them to use the same connection ?!